# Xorg does not see my monitor EDID

Tags: nvidia, resolution, screen

Below is the output from my Xorg.0.

```
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    22.311] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    22.311] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-23-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    22.311] Current Operating System: Linux sean-P55-USB3 3.2.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012 x86_64
[    22.311] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=0a34603e-aee9-44d1-8982-a5a5a38c3e4d ro quiet splash
[    22.311] Build Date: 29 August 2012  12:12:33AM
[    22.311] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    22.311] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    22.311]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    22.311] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    22.311] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Nov 17 13:20:45 2012
[    22.311] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    22.311] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    22.311] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    22.311] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    22.311] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    22.311] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    22.311] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using the first device section listed.
[    22.311] (**) |   |-->Device "Default Device"
[    22.311] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    22.311] (==) Automatically adding devices
```

I have searched all over, and followed lots of dead ends and unanswered questions on this issue. I need to get this monitor recognised so I can use the native resolution of 1600x1200.  The Nvidia driver in Windows has no problem with this. The monitor is an old Iiyama HM204DT A.  Is there a way of configuring Xorg manually to get these working?

I have tried xrandr but this will not work.  Output:-

```
sean@sean-P55-USB3:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1152 x 864, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384       119.9    119.6  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384       120.0  
   400x300       144.4  
   320x240       120.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Tried Nvidia Xorg.config:

sean@sean-P55-USB3:~$ sudo nvidia-xconfig
[sudo] password for sean:

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Default Device" must have a Driver line.

Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as
'/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

How do I insert a driver line?

This is a bit of a pain as I want to use my Vectorworks cad program in a WinXP Vbox at 1600x1200 but all virtual drives are restricted to the host screen resolution.

Do i need to manually create EIDI info in Xorg?

I am slightly confused about how Xorg and Nvidia relate

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$ sudo apt-get install read-edid
$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

If so, what is the output of the last command? Does it give an error message?

sean@sean-P55-USB3:~$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
parse-edid: parse-edid version 2.0.0
get-edid: get-edid version 2.0.0

```
Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
Function supported
Call successful

VBE version 300
VBE string at 0x11100 "NVIDIA"
```

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

```
Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
Function supported
Call successful

Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC2 transfers
0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer
```

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

```
Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
Function supported
Call failed
```

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
parse-edid: IO error reading EDID

Comment: OMG not bad for a Noob!

Managed to write my own xorg.conf file using the steps found here

http://grenage.com/xorg.html

And with the help of my monitor manual and a bit of guesswork

All fixed, Can now see all my monitors resolution and refresh rates in Nvidia control panel!!

Now reset res to 1600x1200@75

I knew that you can do anything in Linux if you dont give up.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution Below Came from answers.launchpad.net](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+question/39299):

In the `Device` section for the video card include the line:

```
Option "IgnoreEDID" "1"
```

In the `Monitor` section include lines for your monitor:

```
Horizsync 28-100
Vertrefresh 60-76
```

Values will vary depending upon your monitor, check the docs for it.